# Elasticsearch with DataTables in Laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel, elasticsearch, datatables

I'm using `DataTables` in `Laravel` and putting dynamic data into it with `ajax`. When I fetch the data from `MySQL` it works but when I fetch it from Elasticsearch it returns an `ajax` error.

```
DataTables warning: table id=htmkl5-extension - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

Comment: Did you follow the instructions mentioned in the error message? If so, what happened? What is the JSON which is causing the error? You can [edit] your question to show us the JSON as formatted text (not a screenshot). Sow us the text of any error messages in the browser console (F12 to access). Show us the DataTable definition, as well. As it currently stands, your question is missing all the information needed for the community to help you.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [tour] and read [ask] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

- This the controller function :

  ```
   if ($request->ajax()) {
      $rawdata = Autorisation::searchByQuery(array('match' => 
        array('nom_autorisation' => 'Autorisation')));

       $data = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($rawdata);

       return DataTables::of($data)
           ->addIndexColumn()


           ->addColumn('action', function ($data) {

               $btns ='<div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Open</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuReference1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="parent">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-down"><polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"></polyline></svg>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuReference1">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="admin/users/'.$data->id.'" class="edit">Edit</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="users/destroy/'.$data->id.'">Delete</a>

                    </div>
                </div>';

               return $btns;
           })

           ->rawColumns(['action'])
           ->make(true);
       }
  ```
- This is the script :

```html
   <script>

    $('#html5-extension').DataTable( {
           
            processing:true,
            serverSide:true,
            ajax:{
                url:"{{route('autorisation')}}",
            },
            columns:[
                {
                    data: 'num_decret', name: 'num_decret'
                } ,
                {
                    data: 'nom_autorisation', name: 'nom_autorisation'
                },
                {
                    data: 'ministere_competent', name: 'ministere_competent'
                },

                {
                    data: 'action', name: 'action',
                    orderable:true,
                    searchable:true
                }
            ]
    });
<script>
```